# Passing javascript Object in DWR method call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dwr

I am trying to pass a Javascript Object to server side using a DWR method call, but getting JS error.

Javascript :

```
var referenceFieldValues = new Object();
var refFieldArray = referenceFields.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<refFieldArray.length;i++ ){
    referenceFieldValues[refFieldArray[i]] = $("#"+refFieldArray[i]).val();
}
DWRRequesthandler.method(fieldId,refObjectId,searchField,searchText,referenceFieldValues,callback);
```

Java Code :

```
public JSONObject method(String fieldId, String refObjectId,String searchField, String searchString, Object referenceFieldValues,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
//some code..
}
```

Request is unable to reach server and DWR throws error. 
referenceFieldValues gets populated like

```
Object { AB_SUP_COM="12345"}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the full error? Have you tried using the developer console on your browser (opens most of the time CMD/Ctrl + Alt/Shift + i Mac/Win). Have you tried to curl your endpoint or another kind of REST-Tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer by myself ,

Just replacing 
`Object referenceFieldValues` to `Map referenceFieldValues` worked well for me..

Thankns lilith for your reply..